# Elasticsearch 5.5.2 - Failed to parse query

Tags: mysql, symfony, elasticsearch

Problem with elasticsearch 5.5.2 - Failed to parse query

Example input with (script tags around the window.location=..):

`[ window.location="http://www.google.be"] [index: src] [reason: all shards failed]`

How can I prevent people from entering scripts in my search field?

Answer (score 0):

### Update

Added a preg match line before I let people's input go through :)
Code example which worked for me:

```
if(!preg_match('#(?<=<)\w+(?=[^<]*?>)#', $searchinput)) {
$gerechten = $finder->find($searchinput);
}
else {
$gerechten = [];
}
```